# Postgres TupleTable like data structure

Tags: postgresql

I'm writing my own `Group by` operator (non-hashed implementation) and I'm currently looking on a good data structure to store the result groups. There are two requirement in my mind: the table need to be efficiently expanded and the tuples within each group need to be sorted.

I carefully examined the implementation of standard `Group by` (both hashed and sorted implementation), the closest I got is to leverage parts of the `TupleHashTable` but before going through this plan, I need to make sure I'm not overlooking an existing data structure.

Comment: What language are you writing this in?  C?

Comment: Yes, I'm using C. I'm implementing my operator inside postgres.

Comment: Sounds like a candidate for http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/. Mail to pgsql-general@postgresql.org. Would be nice to report back here, it that leads to a useful answer.